# Drive 12V Automotive Relay from 3.3v ESP32

Tags: arduino, transistors, mosfet, power-electronics, nodemcu

I am working on a project to start a vehicle using Automotive Relays.  [image] And I am following [this](http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com/henrys-bench/arduino-output-devices/tip122-arduino-relay-tutorial/) circuit in the tutorial to do so. Everything works fine on Arduino UNO. But I want to use ESP32 of this [kind](https://www.amazon.co.uk/JZK-ESP-32S-Development-Bluetooth-Antenna/dp/B071JR9WS9) in my final project and ESP32 is 3.3v with ~12mA max current. When I plug ESP32 to the above-given circuit (Obviously powering through external 5v connection with the shared ground and not 12v battery), it fails to trigger the relay and instead resets. Any suggestions?

My ESP32 Circuit. [image]

Comment: You have shown a schematic of what _does_ work. Can you please post a schematic of what does _not_ work showing any voltage regulators and power supplies.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, running the TIP122 emitter current back to the battery via the ESP32? (If so then you would need to correct your schematic.)

Comment: @Transistor Yes. What would the ideal/optimal circuit if I am using 3.3v ESP32 ?

Comment: You may be running a high-ish current from the relay coil through the board and that might upset it. Try connecting the emitter directly to the battery negative. If you can find the PCB schematic and board layout it may help you understand potential problems. Start on [github](https://github.com/Nicholas3388/LuaNode).

Comment: Okay. Will try to put the emitter directly to the battery and not to ESP32.

Comment: You said that the ESP32 is a 3.3V board. Why is the power supply 5V? Is the board designed to accept 5V? You also need to make sure the GPIO driving the transistor is programmed to be a totem-pole output (drives high and low). Measure the voltage at the D13 output. It must be at least 1.2 V to turn on the transistor which is a Darlington.

Comment: ESP32 GPIO is 3.3V. Board accepts 5V as you can see in the board image given in the here - https://www.amazon.co.uk/JZK-ESP-32S-Development-Bluetooth-Antenna/dp/B071JR9WS9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ESP board has 5V in but runs on 3.3V, has a small ldo on the board to regulate the 5V down. And as the output current rises the output voltage level will drop below 3.3V.

The solution is to replace the TIP NPN Darlington transistor with a logic level N-Channel mosfet. IRLZ44 or STN4NF03L maybe. These are voltage driven instead of current driven and won't have the issues with the ESPs limited current and sagging voltage output.

Alternatively, use a opto isolated relay board/module. The esp would drive a small led based optocoupler that then drives a transistor and the relay.

Or use a smaller relay. Or use a small nfet to drive your Darlington transistor. A bunch of options. The logic level mosfet would be the simplest imho.

Comment: Can i use IRF520 MOSFET module - https://www.aliexpress.com/item/TOP-MOSFET-Button-IRF520-MOSFET-Driver-Module-for-Arduino-ARM-Raspberry-pi/32658018958.html

Comment: Or a IRL4ZZn Mosfet?

Comment: @SurajJorwekar Take a look at Typical Transfer and Output Characteristics graph. IRF520 is not logic level MOSFET. Use IRL4ZZN instead.

Comment: Hey guys unable to find IRLZ44 and STN4NF03L. Please suggest some other equivalent mosfet

Comment: Will this work? RFP30N06LE (https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/RFP30N06LE.pdf)

Comment: just read the word logic level in the datasheet, you'll straightly know that it is logic level mosfet.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a logic level MOSFET. Use 1k gate resistance and don't forget to add a pull-down resistor (10k or so) so that the MOSFET remains OFF when you want it to be OFF ;) Make sure your GPIO pin voltage is at acceptable levels with the pull-down resistor installed. You'll find more details about this in the microcontroller datasheet.